# How to create repeated dates in batches?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to create a list of dates that are repeated in batches of 8 in Excel. I want this repetition to occur from 2019/11/01 to 2020/05/31. See example below. Is there a fast way to do this?

```
 Column A

 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/01
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/02
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
 2019/11/03
```

Comment: Try: `=INT(SEQUENCE(("5/31/2020"-"11/1/2019"+1)*8,,"11/1/2019",1/8))`

Comment: Do I copy and paste this function on a blank cell? I did that and it gave me #VALUE! error message in that cell.

Comment: Yes, you need to place in a blank cell, works with `Excel 2021/MS365`. @Rnoobie i have posted in answers, you can refer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using <kbd>INT( )</kbd> & <kbd>SEQUENCE( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A1</kbd>

```
=INT(SEQUENCE(("5/31/20"-"11/1/19"+1)*8,,"11/1/19",1/8))
```

---

Or,

[image]

---

```
=DATE(2019,11,1)+INT((ROW()-1)/8)
```

---

OfCourse needs to fill down!

---

Or, the above fills till <kbd>5/31/2020</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,DATE(2019,11,1),
     b,DATE(2020,5,31),
     IF(ROW()<=(b-a+1)*8,a+INT((ROW()-1)/8),""))
```

---

Answer (score 1):

I also found that this worked.

```
=DATE(2019,11,1)+INT((ROW()-1)/8)
```

And then you drag and drop as necessary.

Comment: Yes I have posted that as well yesterday.

Comment: I added it again because I couldn't upvote that particular equation.

Comment: Ah okay good. but this one has an issue it wont end till `31-5-2020` if you fill down it will give you some outputs for other months and years, for that reason i have added a improvised one in the below i.e. at last